# how to remove the android device in gmail account

Tags: gmail

one guy is connecting to my gmail account. if I remove the device from gmail account also he again connecting. I don't know how he is connecting again ,I changed my gmail password and 2 step verification is on .. but still he is using my account. kindly help me .

he is using Samsung galxy note 11

Answer (score 0):

- First of all Log in to google in a PC, open gmail and at the bottom you can see `Last account activity`.

  Click `details` shown next to it > and click `sign out of all other sessions.`

  ==========================================================================
- Now, if he has added your account in to his device, follow these steps.

  1. Go to [google account security](https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security#activity) in a browser (PC).
  2. Sign in with your google account
  3. Under `device activity and notifications` click `Review devices` shown inside a card named `recently used devices`
  4. Remove access to the particular device.

  ==========================================================================

### Now, (most important) change your password and do not share it with anyone.